# Como validar rut en formulario

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, spring-mvc

Quisiera saber como valido el ingreso de Rut sin que se repita. Primero debiera de verificar si el rut que se ingresa ya existe en la bd, si no existe se ingresa, y si existe se manda un mensaje de alerta, llevo dias investigando pero ni idea de el como hacerlo.
Soy estudiante y estoy con Spring MVC, MYSQL y usando Netbeans.
Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Mi clase Controlador

```
public class Controlador {
Conexion con = new Conexion();
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(con.Conectar());
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

@RequestMapping(value = "agregar.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView Agregar(){
    mav.addObject(new Persona());
    mav.setViewName("agregar");
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "agregar.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView Agregar(Persona p){
    String sql = "insert into persona(rut,nombre) values (?,?)";
    this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql, e.getRut(), e.nombre());
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/index.htm");
}

}
```

Aqui el error al intentar ingresar un rut que ya existe
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estas usando JPA para la persistencia de datos?

Comment: No, al menos hasta ahora. El código que mostré es todo lo que tengo ya que Spring MVC haría el resto, pero sería todo, funciona el ingresar, solo me faltaría validar el rut. Gracias por responder.

Comment: Para saber si el dato existe, solo lo tenes que buscar. Si está entonces existe y devolves el mensaje de error. Y si no está no existe y lo insertás.

Comment: @Juan, solo repetiste lo que dije en mi pregunta...